# python pandas read_csv() from google spreadsheet url

Tags: url, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to load the data of [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1itaohdPiAeniCXNlntNztZ_oRvjh0HsGuJXUJWET008/edit#gid=0) (a Google Spreadsheet data), in my Jupyter notebook, using python.

I tried different methods and pandas.read_csv() seems to be the easiest. But, I cannot load the data in a proper format. Here is the code that I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
url     = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1itaohdPiAeniCXNlntNztZ_oRvjh0HsGuJXUJWET008/edit#gid=0'
df      = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)
df
```

The output does not look like the Spreadsheet:

[image]

Probably because of data type, that I don't know how to fix. I have tried different ways from other posts, but it didn't help. Here is one of them:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 
import io

url     = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1itaohdPiAeniCXNlntNztZ_oRvjh0HsGuJXUJWET008/edit#gid=0').text
buffer  = io.StringIO(url)
columns = ['ID','age', 'sex','city', 'province', 'country', 
           'wuhan(0)_not_wuhan(1)', 'latitude', 'longitude', 
           'geo_resolution', 'date_onset_symptoms', 'date_admission_hospital', 
           'date_confirmation', 'symptoms', 'lives_in_Wuhan', 'travel_history_dates', 
           'travel_history_location', 'reported_market_exposure', 'additional_information']
df      = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=buffer, header=1, usecols=columns)

df
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the output you expect?

Comment: Have you tried using the CSV export URL instead? `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1itaohdPiAeniCXNlntNztZ_oRvjh0HsGuJXUJWET008/export?format=csv`?